# "borrowed data escapes outside of closure" only when using &mut or threads?

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

When trying to reassign a reference to point somewhere else from inside a closure, I noticed a strange behavior that I cannot explain, shown by this minimal example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo: i32 = 5;
    let mut foo2: i32 = 6;
    let mut borrower = &mut foo; // compiles OK without mut here and below
    let mut c = || {
        borrower = &mut foo2;    // compiles OK without mut here and above
    };
}
```

this yields the following error ONLY when the references are `&mut`:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of closure
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
23 |     let mut borrower = &mut foo;
   |         ------------ `borrower` declared here, outside of the closure body
24 |     let mut c = || {
25 |         borrower = &mut foo2;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What does this error actually mean here? Why would it be unsafe to do this, given that it's clear that the closure is only alive while `foo2` is still alive? Why does it matter whether it's a `&mut` reference or not?

When trying the same from a a scoped thread, it NEVER compiles, with or without `mut`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo: i32 = 5;
    let mut foo2: i32 = 6;
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(&mut foo)); // removing mut does NOT fix it
    println!("{}", a.lock().unwrap());
    
    thread::scope(|s| {
        let aa = a.clone();
        s.spawn(move ||{
            *aa.lock().unwrap() = &mut foo2; // removing mut does NOT fix it
        });
    });
}
```

When `mut` is removed, the program compiles without error.
Why is the behavior different here from the first example, where removing `mut` satisfies the compiler?

My research has lead me to believe that it might have something to do with the FnOnce, FnMut and Fn Traits of closures, but I am stuck.

Comment: [Here's a simpler scoped threads example, without `Mutex`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d02df94714bd79c304b0760ba5bf87a).

Comment: If you remove the `move` keyword in your example, it works, but strangely it works even WITH `&mut`, as opposed to the first example. Strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo: i32 = 5;
    let mut foo2: i32 = 6;
    let mut borrower = &mut foo;
    let mut called = false;
    let mut c = || {
        if !called {
            borrower = &mut foo2;
            called = true;
        } else {
            foo2 = 123;
        }
    };
    c();
    c();
    *borrower = 456;
}
```

If the compiler would look at the code like you wanted it to, this code would be valid: we don't borrow `foo2` in the current branch, so it is not borrowed. But this code is clearly not: we mutate `foo2` while it is borrowed, *from the previous closure call*.

If you'll ask how the compiler figures this out, then we'll need to look at how the desugared closure looks like.

Closures desugars to structs that implement the `Fn` family of traits. Here's how, roughly, our closure desugars:

```rust
struct Closure<'borrower, 'foo2> {
    borrower: &'borrower mut &'foo2 mut i32,
    foo2: &'foo2 mut i32,
}

// Forward `FnOnce` to `FnMut`. This is not really relevant for us, and I left it only for completeness.
impl FnOnce<()> for Closure<'_, '_> {
    type Output = ();
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(mut self, (): ()) -> Self::Output {
        self.call_mut(())
    }
}

impl<'borrower, 'foo2> FnMut<()> for Closure<'borrower, 'foo2> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut<'this>(&'this mut self, (): ()) -> Self::Output {
        *self.borrower = self.foo2;
    }
}

// let mut c = || {
//     borrower = &mut foo2;
// };
let mut c = Closure {
    borrower: &mut borrower,
    foo2: &mut foo2,
}
```

See the problem? We're trying to assign `self.foo2` to `*self.borrower`, but we cannot move out of `self.foo` as we only have a mutable reference to `self`. We can mutably borrow it, but only for the lifetime of `self` - `'this`, and it is not enough. We need the full lifetime `foo2`.

However, when the references are immutable, we don't need to move out of `self.foo2` - we can just *copy* it. This creates a reference with the desired lifetime, because immutable references are `Copy`.

The reason it wants in the code I brought in a comment, without `Mutex` (without `move`, I hope it is obvious why it doesn't work with `move`), is that [`spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.Scope.html#method.spawn) takes `FnOnce`, so the compiler knows we cannot call the closure twice. Technically, We have `self` and not `&mut self`, so we can move out of its fields.

It works if we force `FnOnce` too:

```rust
fn force_fnonce(f: impl FnOnce()) {}
force_fnonce(|| {
    borrower = &mut foo2;
});
```

The reason it does not work with your scoped threads snippet, even though it requires `FnOnce`, is completely different: it's again because of the `move`. Because of it, `foo2` is local to the closure, and borrowing it yields a reference that is only valid in the closure, as it is destroyed when the closure exits. Fixing it requires borrowing `foo2` instead of moving it. We cannot get rid of the `move` because of `aa`, so we need to *partially move* closure captures. The way to do that is as follows:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo: i32 = 5;
    let mut foo2: i32 = 6;
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(&mut foo));
    println!("{}", a.lock().unwrap());

    thread::scope(|s| {
        let aa = a.clone();
        let foo2_ref = &mut foo2;
        s.spawn(move || {
            *aa.lock().unwrap() = foo2_ref;
        });
    });
}
```

And this code indeed compiles, even with the `&mut`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great explanation. However, it seems to me that the compiler's error message in this case is not very clear, considering that it says "borrowed data escapes outside of closure", when it seems to be more of a case of "cannot move mutable reference out of closure".

Comment: @JMC Instead of moving, it tries to reborrow it, like `&mut *self.foo2`. But this results in a reference with a shorter lifetime, so "borrowed data escapes outside of closure".